# How to specify PDF file name during conversion in Docx4J

Tags: java, pdf, docx4j

I need to output the resulted PDF within the browser. This is what I have so far

```
public void displayWordAsPDF(InputStream inputStream,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        PhysicalFonts.setRegex(".*(calibri|camb|cour|arial|symb|times|Times|zapf).*");
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(inputStream);
        // Set up font mapper (optional)
        Mapper fontMapper = new IdentityPlusMapper();
        wordMLPackage.setFontMapper(fontMapper);

        PhysicalFont font = PhysicalFonts.get("Arial Unicode MS");
        // make sure this is in your regex (if any)!!!
        if (font != null) {
            fontMapper.put("Times New Roman", font);
            fontMapper.put("Arial", font);
        }
        fontMapper.put("Libian SC Regular", PhysicalFonts.get("SimSun"));

        Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, response.getOutputStream());

    }
```

The above code converts the docx file into PDF file (however the file name is still the same `e.g something.docx`, thus the file will be downloaded locally). If I rename the downloaded file extension into .pdf then I am only able to open it up in my Adobe Reader.

My question is how I can specify the file name as well as the extension during the conversion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less a docx4j issue, and more one with updating your `HttpServletResponse` object appropriately. Something like this should do the job:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"something.pdf\"");
```